# Circuit flow of current

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am having some problems trying to figure out the voltage between node a and b(Vab). The part that is confusing me is where the 4A and 3 Ohms are parallel. How do I know what the current will be going through the 3 Ohm resistor?

Can you just assume it to be the same as its input current(2A)

[image: Circuit]

Comment: What is the value of the resistor between a and b ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little rusty with Norton \$ \to \$ Thevenin conversion, so folks feel welcome in pointing out any errors.

[image]

We take the encircled portions as norton circuits and convert them to their corresponding thevenin counterparts as below:

[image]

With a little straightening of connections and lumping the 3 and 4 ohm resistors followed by applying KCl at the nodes of the current source:

[image]

---

The rest is, I hope, easy to infer from the simplified circuit.

Comment: In your last drawing, How did you determine that 1A flows one way and 2 A flows the other way without even knowing the value of the mystery resistor?

Comment: The 1A flowing into the voltage source on the left was already given in the post by OP, hence I inferred the 2A remaining must come from the unknown resistor.

Answer (score 0):

KCL says that the current entering the node on the left must be the same as the node exiting on the right. Therefore, the current going through the resistor is the current going through the parallel subcircuit minus the current going through the current source.

Comment: Yeah I know KCL. There are 2A entering the subcircuit and 6A leaving because of the 4A current source. Am I to assume that the 2A all go to the resistor?

Comment: No, there is 2A entering and there is 2A exiting. KCL says so.

Comment: Then where does the 4A come in to play?

Comment: As part of the subcircuit.